# Function modifier effect on return value

Tags: solidity, modifiers

Having the following code

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

contract TestModifier {

    mapping (address => bool) public authorities;
    mapping (address => address) public authorized;

    modifier onlyAuthorized(address _user) {
        require(authorities[authorized[_user]], "Requires authorization");
        _;
    }

    // returns false
    function getStatus1(address _user) external view returns (bool) {
        return authorities[authorized[_user]];
    }

    // returns true
    function getStatus2(address _user) external view onlyAuthorized(_user) returns (bool) {
        return authorities[authorized[_user]];
    }

    // returns true
    function getStatus3(address _user) external view onlyAuthorized(_user) returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Given any address as the input to `getStatus` functions, I expect to see `false` as the return value for the first one and an error for the other two. However, `getStatus1` returns `false` and two others return `true`.

The [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/contracts.html#function-modifiers) states

> In an earlier version of Solidity, return statements in functions having modifiers behaved differently.

Is there any better explanation for this behavior?

## NodeJS Test

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"authorities","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"authorized","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"getStatus1","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"getStatus2","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"getStatus3","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
const address = "0x2e2d61Cb7725b5d381879030d308508d26759aDC";

/************ TESTING Ropsten ***********/
const web3Ropsten = new Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/17a6aa646dfb46ab880ff2c8aa24cbea");
const contractRopsten = new web3Ropsten.eth.Contract(abi, "0x4457f104861f09240d09d857987290f928d09a1e");

contractRopsten.methods.getStatus1(address).call({}, function(error, result){
    console.log("Ropsten::status1: ", result);
});
contractRopsten.methods.getStatus2(address).call({}, function(error, result){
    console.log("Ropsten::status2: ", result);
});
contractRopsten.methods.getStatus3(address).call({}, function(error, result){
    console.log("Ropsten::status3: ", result);
});

/************ TESTING Kovan ***********/
const web3Kovan = new Web3("https://kovan.infura.io/v3/17a6aa646dfb46ab880ff2c8aa24cbea");
const contractKovan = new web3Kovan.eth.Contract(abi, "0x552748c93a38939f1330629a3016a97accd6d0d9");

contractKovan.methods.getStatus1(address).call({}, function(error, result){
    console.log("Kovan::status1: ", result);
});
contractKovan.methods.getStatus2(address).call({}, function(error, result){
    if (error) {
        console.error("Kovan::status2: ", error.message);
    } else {
        console.log("Kovan::status2: ", result);
    }
});
contractKovan.methods.getStatus3(address).call({}, function(error, result){
    if (error) {
        console.error("Kovan::status3: ", error.message);
    } else {
        console.log("Kovan::status3: ", result);
    }
});
```

Comment: A better explanation - sure, you're calling `getStatus1` with a different input than each one of the other two functions.

Comment: Another explanation - after calling `getStatus1` and before calling the other two functions, you are calling a function (which does not show up in your question, but exists in your actual code) to set those two mappings.

Comment: I tried your code with remix.ethereum.org and it works as expected. How are you testing?

Comment: I tried it with truffle. Worked as expected. Wonder if you can share us the contract address in a testnet so I can try to call the functions in your deployed version.

Comment: Ropsten testnet with this address: 0x1C50aDCe3279Ddf577ce15738D8f046B8f647f9b

Comment: @goodvibration I'm calling it via remix.ethereum.org and also from code.

Comment: @AlexW, With the latest update of macOS I can't run Ganache for the moment. But using Ropsten testnet I get this strange result. I get this result with any Eth address as argument e.g. 0x2e2d61Cb7725b5d381879030d308508d26759aDC

Comment: FYI. Just tried your contract in Ropsten. Getting true for 2 and 3. Very strange. Ganache returns "Requires authorization" as expected.

Comment: @AlexW: Nothing strange here. When you run in Ganache, you compile the source code beforehand. When you run in Ropsten, you use the bytecode of god knows what code (most likely not the same as the source code in this question). Until this dude verifies that specific contract address on Etherscan, we won't know for sure, be we can pretty much bet that it ain't the same as what he's posted here.

Comment: @goodvibration I don't understand why r u so rude and negative? Do I Know you?!!!!
You can deploy this in Ropsten by yourself. Or tell me how to prove that this the exact code and I will do it. If you think I'm not honest then stop replying. I didn't force you to spend time here. I have a question and I'm trying to find an answer for it.

Comment: @AlexW I just tried it in Kovan testnet and there it worked as expected. 2 & 3 returned error. So there should be a difference between Ropsten and Kovan test net I assume.

Comment: @MehranShakeri: Why do you say that??? Nothing rude about what I wrote to my understanding, so I apologize for the offense taken. I wrote very explicitly how you could prove this, and that's by verifying your contract on Etherscan, so we can all see its code, and then there will no longer any doubts.

Comment: OK, I even did that for you, and guess what? Verification on etherscan has failed, which means that the code in your question is **NOT** the code on Ropsten address `0x1C50aDCe3279Ddf577ce15738D8f046B8f647f9b`. So please find a way to convince us in other means, for example by providing here the **exact** code of your contract.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you again for taking your time. during the debug I was changing the smart contract a bit and it might be that one of those small changes was applied in that address. 
I just copy pasted my code from this question in remix, deployed it in Ropsten and repeated the test.
Here is the smart contract address: 0x4457F104861f09240D09d857987290f928D09a1E
The tx which created it:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe0f86e71e5b314347932af9861a369646fff6fdf740a86cdc3625f7474a49ee5

And it still behaves as I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I'm a beginner and if there is any extra info I should provide please let me know. If you have time, you should be able to reproduce this using remix and this code. Or let me know how can I give you more information

Comment: Is the code of the contract at address `0x4457F104861f09240D09d857987290f928D09a1E` exactly the same as what you posted in your question?

Comment: Yes. Deployed vis remix and metamask

Comment: @goodvibration So I learned something new :) I uploaded the code via "VerifyContract". Hopefully this is what you were asking for.
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4457f104861f09240d09d857987290f928d09a1e#code

Comment: Haha, I just tried to verify it on Etherscan 20 seconds ago, and got `Contract source code already verified`. OK, let me try to call your functions.

Comment: So what `_user` are you calling these functions with? Nevermind, I was just able to reproduce your claim with a `_user` of my choice. Let me investigate on that...

Comment: OK, so I believe that this is a compiler bug, which you might want to report on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity). Function `getStatus1` behaves correctly. Function `getStatus2` should revert, and even if it shouldn't have, it should still return `false`. Function `getStatus3` should also revert, but at least it returns the correct value. My guess is that this compiler version doesn't handle modifiers the way it should (or maybe they are no longer allowed on `pure`/`view` functions).

Comment: This guess doesn't quite explain why function `getStatus2` returns `true`, unless the entire handing of modifiers in this compiler version has gone completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  I will create an issue in Github and reference to this link.

Comment: Wait, don't just yet. I've deployed [an instance of it using solc 0.5.13](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xE5852D4E2f6349619de2c8fD770f6C387bB91Cd0#readContract) and [an instance of it using solc 0.4.26](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xba010256169b2DC009224951bC3B15A5844Fd65a#readContract), and they're behaving the same as yours. So the problem has to be elsewhere.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106050/discussion-on-question-by-mehran-shakeri-function-modifier-effect-on-return-valu).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in either web3.js OR the node that you're communicating with.

It happens only if the `require` statement includes an error-message.

It happens when the node is Infura, but not when the node is Ganache.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. If I understood it correctly, you mean calling these functions form source code should return properly. Actually I faced this issue first from the backend call.
I've updated my question to include a NodeJS code and when I run it, it still returns wrong values from Ropsten.

Comment: @MehranShakeri: I'm actually re-investigating this. See [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/80921), it seems to be exactly the same problem. Technically, web3.js throws an exception when the contract function returns the revert opcode. I suspect that after the upgrade of the public networks (mainnet, ropsten, kovan, etc) to Constantinople, something has changed, for which web3.js doesn't handle it correctly anymore. Since most apps are using web3.js, that leads to a problem. When I deploy your contract on a (local) Ganache network, every function works as expected.

Comment: I will try to interact with your contract on Ropsten.

Comment: @MehranShakeri: Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Currently I removed the modifier from the function to continue with development.