# Web3 1.2.6 appears to ignore require in view function

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3js-v1.x, web3js-v0.x

Given the following function:

```
    function checkLock() external view returns (bool) {
        require(
            address(this) == IERC721(_nftRegistryAddress).ownerOf(_tokenId),
            "[checkLock] Contract is not owner of tokenId"
        );
        return true;
    }
```

The correct state is `false` - the contract does not own the NFT.

If I call this function with Metamask's web3, i.e. 0.20.7, it correctly returns `false`.

If I call this function with web3 1.2.6, it incorrectly returns `true`!

I'm aware that relying on a require to return state is nonstandard, but would be interested in understanding the discrepancy.

Comment: `I'm aware that relying on a require to return state is nonstandard` - it's not returning anything. The line below it returns `true`. And BTW, you may as well get rid of that line (as well as the `returns (bool)` in the function declaration), because it's never going to return anything else. Either the function-call completes successfully, or it reverts (so you can simply rely on that in order to determine the status).

Comment: `If I call this function with Metamask's web3, i.e. 0.2.7, it correctly returns false` - this function **does not** return anything other than true!

Comment: @goodvibration ok, so let me reformulate: why does it appear to revert with 0.2.7 and not with 1.2.6?

Comment: `If I call this function with web3 1.2.6` - how do you call this function?

Comment: @goodvibration I instantiate the contract and use `.call()` for both versions.

Comment: Do you have a NodeJS script to do that for each case? If yes, then can you please share it? Can you also print the address of your contract, and then independently call `nftRegistry.ownerOf(tokenId)` from that script and tell us what it returns?

Comment: @goodvibration https://gist.github.com/jmahhh/c15bf25e5837ca584e5d4c7a2118b934, I called the registry at 0xb1f41815C2114C7BB27254507E59df2675F55F1C and confirmed that the owner is not the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in either web3.js OR the node that you're communicating with.

It happens only if the `require` statement includes an error-message.

It happens when the node is Infura, but not when the node is Ganache.

Note that your function shouldn't be returning `false` in either case.

Either it returns `true`, or the function-call reverts.